# consul & connect undefined: freeport.GetOne

Tags: go, consul

I copied a piece of code from [`consul doc`](https://www.consul.io/docs/connect/native/go) to `main.go` file

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "github.com/hashicorp/consul/api"
    "github.com/hashicorp/consul/connect"
)

func main() {

    // Create a Consul API client
    client, _ := api.NewClient(api.DefaultConfig())

    // Create an instance representing this service. "my-service" is the
    // name of _this_ service. The service should be cleaned up via Close.
    svc, _ := connect.NewService("my-service", client)
    defer svc.Close()

    // Get an HTTP client
    httpClient := svc.HTTPClient()

    // Perform a request, then use the standard response
    resp, _ := httpClient.Get("http://web.service.consul/autoCode/getColumn")

    buf, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    fmt.Println(string(buf))
}
```

then execute below steps in sequence

```golang
go mod init
go get -u -v github.com/hashicorp/consul/api
go get -u -v github.com/hashicorp/consul/connect
go mod tidy
go test
```

Output error:

> **\go\pkg\mod\github.com\hashicorp\consul@v1.11.4\connect\testing.go:112:42: undefined: freeport.GetOne**

OS: win10
Go version:1.17.7

Can anyone help me solve this question.  THANKS.

Comment: It looks like the consul module has not yet been updated to point to the new sdk version. You can probably update the sdk version locally, or use `replace`.

Comment: @nil please check the answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in consul [`go.mod`](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/e3e481022e0abb08e0e3dc7e22b635df10f71672/go.mod#L36) which is using consul sdk version `v0.8.0` which does not has [`freeport.GetOne`](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/e3e481022e0abb08e0e3dc7e22b635df10f71672/sdk/freeport/freeport.go#L425) implementation to resolve the issue you need to install consul sdk version `v0.9.0`.

Steps:

```
go mod init sample
go get -v github.com/hashicorp/consul/api
go get -v github.com/hashicorp/consul/sdk@v0.9.0
go get -v github.com/hashicorp/consul/connect
go mod tidy
go test
```